# Using a Parameter from a query in a Report

Tags: ms-access

I'm using a query in which a enter parameter box appears for a user to enter a month and year and the query shows sales data for that time period.

When I create a report based on this query, how can I pass the entered value to the report so it can be used in a string? Eg. If they Enter in May for the month and 2014 for the year, The title of the report will be sales for May 2014.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression as ControlSource for a textbox:

```
=DateSerial([Please enter year],[Please enter month],1)
```

Now specify for the Format property of the textbox: mmmm yyyy